# differences between suggesting theme_hook in node and page preprocess function

Tags: nodes, hooks, theming

I used to suggest the theme hooks in `MyTheme_preprocess_page()` function in `template.php`. I mean some thing like this:

```
$suggest = "page__node__ContentType";
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
```

and I was wondering why `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>` in the `page--node--ContentType.tpl.php` doesn't display the comment form. finally I tried suggesting theme hook in the `MyTheme_preprocess_node()` function and I saw comment form works ! what are differences between suggesting theme hook in these two functions? and which one is preferable?

Comment: Because the comment form isn't relevant to the page, it only makes sense in the context of a node template

Comment: @Clive what else isn't relevant to the page? I mean is it good idea to always suggest theme hooks in node preprocess?

Comment: Lots of things aren't relevant to the page, I can't list all those out :) Any number of modules that you have installed can alter the variables available to any template file so it's impossible to say. Theme hook suggestions are not related to that at all, by the way - they're just used to choose which template file is served